# How can I repopulate react table form fields selected within the list of total available?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using react 18, Material UI 5 I'm displaying a simple table from data using the map function.

I have another data set (selectedData) that contains the data a user has previous selected. I'm struggling to find the correct syntax to check the id against the selectedData so that I can pre-populate the text field with a selected data value should it exist.

```
<TableBody>
    {data.map((item) => (
        <TableRow key={item.id} sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}>
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{item.name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                <TextField onChange={(e) => handleItem(e, item.id)} sx={{ maxWidth: 50 }}></TextField>
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    ))}
</TableBody>
```

I thought I could do something like:

`selectedData.find(existingItem => existingItem.id === item.id)`

However, I can't seem to find the correct JSX syntax to put it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a controlled input textfield with value being assigned to item.text (I assume) and in case if there is a value in selectedData then you want to prefill the value.
To achieve this first you can prefill the values in the data itself inside an useEffect hook. So that you dont have to struggle with two arrays while rendering.

```
useEffect(()=>{
let temp = []
data.map((item)=>{
  let existingObj =  selectedData.find(existingItem => existingItem.id === item.id)
  temp.push( existingObj ? existingObj : item )
})
//update the data with prefilled values either using setState or calling action dispatcher
 setData(temp)
},[])
```

now in the textfield you can simply map the data.text

```
 <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            <TextField onChange={(e) => handleItem(e, item.id)} 
            sx={{ maxWidth: 50 }} 
            value={data.text}>
            </TextField>
 </TableCell>
```

Let me know if my understanding of the issue is wrong, or your expectation is different.